# Skobbler (GPS Navigation) does not open at specified location

Tags: ios

I have the following code for opening Skobbler at specified location:

```
- (void)openSkobblerWithLatitude:(double)latitude longitude:(double)longitude {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:
        @"hybridnavigation://cmd=mapOverview&latitude=%f&longitude=%f", 
        latitude, 
        longitude]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```

It opens Skobbler, but the location is completely ignored. Is there something wrong with the URL or is this simply a bug in Skobbler?

Link for downloading Skobbler:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/gps-navigation-sat-nav/id370144231?mt=8

**EDIT:** This is what the final URL looks like:

```
"hybridnavigation://cmd=mapOverview&latitude=49.010066&longitude=8.396355"
```

Comment: Umm.. just curious: The values in the URL are correctly filled? ;)

Comment: I have similar code for Apple Maps and Google Maps, so it should be, but I could double check of course...

Comment: Well, the URL looks correct to me and according to the Skobbler message board. Indeed seems to be a Skobbler bug!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted skobbler's support and they confirmed that this is a bug on their side:

> The command line integration does not work with the current version of the app. This problem will be fixed with the upcoming update. (At the moment, I cannot tell you an exact release date.)

Comment: Have you had update on this ? It does not seem to work yet.

Comment: @FKDev I'm not developing that app anymore, so there was no reason for me to follow up. I would suggest that you drop them an email and ask for an update. If you get one you could come back here and share it with us.